# Wallet balance reset

Tags: bitcoin-core, balance

Maybe my question will be stupid, but still I hope for help.
Launched a wallet. Synchronized with the network, and my balance dropped to 0.
According to the history, it was written that the last transaction was July 1, but this is not my business, I didn’t even open the wallet.
I attach a screenshot.[image]

Comment: if it not you, so it is someone who have your wallet keys, or maybe malware.

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't you, it was very likely that you were hacked. There are many possibilities, a virus, a phishing site, etc.

You could check the transactions and their destination addresses, so you can see where the funds have moved

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I can’t see the story (
When I sent the funds, I can see the delivery address and a single arrow icon. In this case, apart from the date and amount of the transfer, there is nothing more (